# Jquery toggle timeout that hide

Tags: jquery

I am trying to hide `div` by timeout after show it by `toggle`. To show it I use `$('#slidable').animate({width: 'toggle'});` I add `.delay(2000).hide();` but seems its does not work. Why?

Code:

```
<script>
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $( "#side" ).click(function() {
     $('#slidable').animate({width: 'toggle'}).delay(2000).hide();
      });
  })
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hide()` is only an animated method if a speed is passed, otherwise it's not added to the fx queue, and `delay()` won't work :

```
$('#slidable').animate({width: 'toggle'}).delay(2000).hide(1);
```

You could even pass zero !

Answer (score 1):

Best way you can handle this is using the complete callback of animate, since `hide` without any duration is not passed into the fx queues.

```
$('#slidable').animate({width: 'toggle'}, function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the "complete" callback of animate().
This way the delay starts, when the toggle finished.
For example:

```
$('#slidable').animate({
        width: 'toggle'
    }, 400, function () {
        $('#slidable').delay(2000).hide();
    })
});
```